# What technology does google analytics use to show the map?

Tags: api, google, visualisation

Does anyone know what technology is used by google analytics in the Geo location tab?

It looks like a combination of image and vector. Is it WMS & WFS or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'maps' in Google Analytics' Dashboard come from Google Charts. You can find an example on how to use Google Charts's GeoCharts over here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: i was not aware of that tech by google, so thanks!

Comment: At first glance it looks a bit like TopoJson